# Where to save my custom scripts so that my python scripts can access the module in the default directory?

Tags: python, import, directory, native

This is going to be a multi-part question but the ultimate aim is such that I can access custom-made modules/libraries/functions like how I do in native python.

**Where are the non-native but `pip` installed python libraries stored and how to configure my interpreter/IDE to access them?**

My users' script all starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**What's the difference between accessing from `/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin/env`, will the custom-made modules that should import like native python modules/packages work?**

**Should my custom scripts become packages? if so how do I make the user-side code, checks for `ImportError` and install/setup these packages in the `try-except`?** e.g.

```
try:
  import module_x
except ImportError:
  # Install package, but how to do it within the script?
  pass
```

**Is there a place to store my custom scripts such that it imports like a native library?** If so, where? What are the consequences?

Comment: The `/usr/bin` vs. `/usr/bin/env` issue is (almost certainly) not something you need worry about.  When you specify `/usr/bin/python` you're telling the shell exactly where to find the `python` binary.  When you say `/usr/bin/env` you're telling the shell to find the `python` binary on its own.  If you only have one copy of `python` on your machine, then the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, you've asked a lot of questions; I will address the one in the subject line.

You can put Python module files anywhere you want and still `import` them without any problems as long as they are in your [module search path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).  You can influence your module search path by altering the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` in your shell before invoking Python, or by altering the [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) variable inside your code.

So if you've installed `/home/alvas/python/lib/module_x.py` and `/usr/local/python/lib/foo.py` you could run:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/alvas/python/lib:/usr/local/python/lib /home/alvas/scripts/bar.py
```

and then the statements

```
import module_x
import foo
```

should simply work.

Alternatively you could do something like this in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/alvas/python/lib')
import module_x
sys.path.append('/usr/local/python/lib')
import foo
```

Either approach will work.

Comment: if I use the latter approach it does not work. I use python3.6 in Anaconda. I I append the new path to sys.path, it gets appended but if I exit and start python again, it is no longer in the list. What am I doing wrong?