# How to make a reusable Python file, as a global package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Let's say I have coded my own function `get_smiley_face()` in the file `fun.py`.
I want the package/file `fun` accessible through my whole pc, so that I can just type `import fun` and then use `fun.get_smiley_face()`. Think of this like the module requests, which is global aswell.

I know that normal Python files can do this [like this article explains](https://www.makeuseof.com/create-import-reuse-module-python/), but it needs to be in the same folder for that to work.

I want to have a central Python file, so that I don't have redundant copies around my projectfolders. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: pip editable installs. Check [this](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial on how to package. You don't need to build the distribution. Just use `pip -e .` in the folder where your package is. It can be anywhere on the system.

Comment: Check out this other SO question on [Where to save my custom scripts so that my python scripts can access the module in the default directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843088/where-to-save-my-custom-scripts-so-that-my-python-scripts-can-access-the-module)

Comment: @demberto Thanks! I think that was the thing I was looking for. If I understand correctly, the other answer needs to have a setup.py and needs to be built everytime it is updated?

Comment: No, but you need to modify PYTHONPATH or `sys.path` everytime before opening Python. Once you install a package in editable mode, you can use it as long as it is not uninstalled from pip or moved somewhere else.